# Mongodb date range fetching data is not working in aggregation

Tags: php, mongodb

Below is my one of sample document in mongodb

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59c5fcedc817c3da1b8b456a"),
"zoneid" : "20",
"accountid" : "34",
"sitename" : "aaa",
"requestid" : "2efa1052-7255-41cd-9d39-8628dac5ed3e",
"winbid" : NumberLong("1"),
"bidder" : "innity",
"cpm" : NumberLong("1"),
"responsetime" : NumberLong("207"),
"slotid" : "20x300x250x34x9206",
"viewerid" : "_87cd184234b181d1c601144adc0c3621",
"uniquecount" : NumberLong("0"),
"datetime" : "2017-09-23 06:19:25"
}
```

and below is my code to fetch data in mongodb in php,

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            "_id" => array(
                "slotid" => '$slotid',
                "bidder" => '$bidder',
                "viewerid" => '$viewerid',
                "datetime" => '$datetime'
            ) ,
            "total" => array(
                '$sum' => 1
            ) ,
            "sitename" => array(
                '$addToSet' => '$sitename'
            ) ,
            "aid" => array(
                '$addToSet' => '$accountid'
            ) 
        ) 
    ) ,
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            "datetime" => array(
                '$gt' => '2017-09-23 06:00:00'
            )
        )
    )
);
$reqbids = $db->requestbids->aggregate($ops);
```

Its return empty result but if I remove either '$group' array or '$match' array means result will shown,but both will used means empty result shown,like below query its shown result

```
    $ops = array(
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            "_id" => array(
                "slotid" => '$slotid',
                "bidder" => '$bidder',
                "viewerid" => '$viewerid',
                "datetime" => '$datetime'
            ) ,
            "total" => array(
                '$sum' => 1
            ) ,
            "sitename" => array(
                '$addToSet' => '$sitename'
            ) ,
            "aid" => array(
                '$addToSet' => '$accountid'
            ) 
        ) 
    )
);
$reqbids = $db->requestbids->aggregate($ops);
```

In above query I removed '$match' array , then its shown result.whats the issue in the code,Anyone help to solve my problem,Any help appreciated...

Comment: Move the `$match` before the `$group`. Change your dates from string to date type or at least use ISO formatted date like `2017-09-23T13:03:35Z` for string comparison to work.

Comment: yeah , now just moving $match before $group , now working...!